# Are lists implicitly 'global' inside of functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I was experimenting with this code:

```
def a():
    #global p
    p.append(4);
    d=9

p=[2,3];
d=8
a();
print p  # ----> [2, 3, 4]
print d  # ----> 8
```

The variable `d` value is not changed as I didn't use the `global` keyword. But the list `p` was modified in function even though I didn't use `global`. Are all lists `global` by default in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical difference is the assignment here.  You are fine calling methods on existing global objects, but you can't assign to them without calling them `global`.  In your code, the name `d` is being reassigned to reference another value. If you changed `p` with assignment you'd have a similar result

```
def a():
    p = [5, 7]  # new local variable, doesn't change global
    p.append(9)  # doesn't change global p
```

This makes sense if you think about what happens when python encounters the name for the first time. In the function you've provided, python will see `p.append` and say "hm, I don't have a local by the name `p`, let me look in the enclosing scope." It sees the global `p` and uses that.

In the example I've shown, python will say "there's no explicit `global` so I assume this is supposed to be a new local variable." and create one.

Names in python are just references. If python followed the behavior you are expecting you'd need a `global` for every function you called, let me explain:

```
def a():
    p.append(1)  # I should need 'global p' to do this
```

This would mean if you had

```
def g():
    ...

def f():
    g()  # this would also need 'global g', otherwise how does it see g?

def f2():
    global g
    def g():  # changes the global g function
        return 0
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `p` is visible to function `a` even though `p` is not global? This is different than how many other languages would work right?

Comment: @rbierman I think you have got the things backwards. **All names defined at the top level of a module are global**. However the whole function declration is a single scope in python, so a name `x` can refer either to a local variable *or* a global one. If you put an assignment to `x` in the function python decides that *all* references to name `x` inside that function body are to that local variable. If no assignment is found then python looks up the enclosing scopes and finds the global name `x`.

Comment: @rbierman in which example are you saying that `p` is not global?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, But In my code, i didnt use global KW. so when the subroutine sees p.append(),  how it can modify the global p array? Also in this append case, then what is difference between using global p and not using global p in function as both gives same result of modifying p array?

Comment: @syam since there is no `p` local variable assigned anywhere in `a`, it looks in the enclosing scope for something named `p`.  If in your function you had *assigned* to `p` that would introduce a local variable

Comment: @syam if all you're doing is calling methods on `p` then it won't make any difference whether or not you use `global`.  Keep in mind that every name in python is just a reference to an object, there's not much difference between how the names `a`, `p`, and `d` work in your example.  If you always needed to use `global` to access a non-local variable, you'd need a `global` for every function you called!

Comment: @Ryan, So in my function 'a', since there is no p variable, it takes it as local. im using  p.append(4) inside the function, it should return  [2,3] only if i printed p outside the function na ?as p treat as a local i the subroutine a. I have little confusion on this :-)

Comment: @syam since there is no `p` in `a` it takes it as a *global* (slight oversimplification here). Every time you call `a` it will append another `4`. Maybe you'd understand this more if you tried printing `p` inside of `a`?

Comment: @syam the lookup ordering follows python's [LEGB rules](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html)

Comment: @RyanHaining thanx man...

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you, that makes sense to me now